# Is it possible to run a main Servlet and a ProxyServlet within :8888 in webdefault.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

I have a webapp that runs within a jetty servlet.

When it starts, it runs on localhost:8888/

I'm using a separate Ruby / Sinatra process to manage my assets (js, css, images).
This runs on localhost:3000/

Ideally, I would like a Jetty ProxyServlet that sends any requests from localhost:8888/assets/* to localhost:3000/assets/* as to avoid cross-domain errors.

This is only in development, my production assets will be served elsewhere so don't answer in the context of scalability or other concerns.

Also, I would need these two "Servlets" to run sidebyside within the same PORT 8888?

So again...
All requests to localhost:8888/* (except, /assets/*) would route to the main webapp servlet.
All requests to localhost:8888/assets/* would route to the ruby / sinatra server localhost:3000/assets/*

**My current webdefault.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  metadata-complete="true"
  version="2.5"
>

  <description>
    Default web.xml file.  
    This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file
  </description>
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

  <listener>
   <listener-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
   <listener-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.IntrospectorCleaner</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>aliases</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>acceptRanges</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>welcomeServlets</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>redirectWelcome</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCacheSize</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCachedFileSize</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCachedFiles</param-name>
      <param-value>2048</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>gzip</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--
    <init-param>
      <param-name>resourceCache</param-name>
      <param-value>resourceCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <!--
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
      <param-value>max-age=3600,public</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- ********************************************************************* -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Railo -->

  <servlet id="Railo">
    <description>Railo CFML Engine</description>
    <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--
    <init-param>
      <param-name>railo-server-root</param-name>
      <param-value>/var/Railo/config/server/</param-value>
      <description>Railo Server configuration directory (for Server-wide configurations, settings, and libraries)</description>
    </init-param>
    !-->
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <!--
    <init-param>
      <param-name>railo-web-directory</param-name>
      <param-value>/var/Railo/config/web/{web-context-label}/</param-value> 
      <description>Railo Web Directory (for Website-specific configurations, settings, and libraries)</description>
    </init-param>
    !-->
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>   
    <url-pattern>/index.cfc/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/admin/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/lms/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.cfml/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- Railo REST Servlet - handles Railo's RESTful web services             -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <servlet id="RESTServlet">
    <description>Railo Servlet for RESTful services</description>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>railo.loader.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- Railo MessageBroker Servlet - Flex Gateway                            -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <servlet id="MessageBrokerServlet">
    <description>Railo Servlet for Flex Gateway</description>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- init-param>
      <param-name>services.configuration.file</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param !-->
    <!-- init-param>
      <param-name>messageBrokerId</param-name>
      <param-value>_default_</param-value>
    </init-param !-->
    <!-- load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup !-->
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flex2gateway/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/flashservices/gateway/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!--                                                 Railo Definitions End -->  
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- _____________________________________________________________________ -->


  <!-- ==================================================================== -->
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <!-- ==================================================================== -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.cfm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <!-- welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file !-->
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- ==================================================================== -->
  <locale-encoding-mapping-list>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ar</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-6</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>be</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>bg</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ca</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>cs</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>da</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>de</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>el</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-7</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>en</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>es</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>et</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>fi</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>fr</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>hr</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>hu</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>is</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>it</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>iw</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-8</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ja</locale><encoding>Shift_JIS</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ko</locale><encoding>EUC-KR</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>lt</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>lv</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>mk</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>nl</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>no</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>pl</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>pt</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ro</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>ru</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sh</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sk</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sl</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sq</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sr</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>sv</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>tr</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-9</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>uk</locale><encoding>ISO-8859-5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>zh</locale><encoding>GB2312</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
    <locale-encoding-mapping><locale>zh_TW</locale><encoding>Big5</encoding></locale-encoding-mapping>
  </locale-encoding-mapping-list>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
  </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

I was thinking something like this?
But it just causes `503 Service Unavailable`

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JettyProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.servlet.ProxyServlet$Transparent</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <!-- This points to the actual server where requests are proxied to -->
     <param-name>ProxyTo</param-name>
     <param-value>http://localhost:3000/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <!-- This will be stripped off the client request URL -->
     <param-name>Prefix</param-name>
     <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JettyProxy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Is this possible? If so, how would it be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tag says you are using **jetty-8** but your proxy servlet class indicates **jetty-6** (the `org.mortbay.servlet.ProxyServlet`).  On jetty-8 the ProxyServlet you should be using is `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet` and yes, this all sounds like a perfectly normal use case.

Comment: I ended up solving this with Jetty Rewrite ProxyRule but now that I understand start.ini and things a bit more I think I could have done this with ProxyServlet as well.

Thank you!